# regex for renamig files using powershell script

Tags: windows, powershell, regex, file-management

i am looking for a way to remove `(file-number)` part from `file name (file-number).extension` and put number in front of file name before a underline.
so `new pics (1).jpg` will be renamed to `1_new pics.jpg`

i have tried `ls | rename-item -newname {$_ -replace '(.*) ((\d+)).(.*)', '$2_$1.$3'}`but i couldnt find a working one

Comment: A man had a problem. He used regular expressions. Now he has two problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did it for me:

```
ls | Rename-Item -NewName {$_ -replace '(.*)\((\d+)\)\.(.*)', '$2_$1.$3' }
```

Comment: `ls | rename-item -newname {$_ -replace '(.*) \((\d+)\).(.*)', '$2_$1.$3' }`
this one removes space between filename and extension in output